# Dropdown menu does not expand - Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to setup a hamburger menu using bootstrap. I went through my code, added in the css and js files, and the menu does not work i.e. it does not expand. I have used the example code from the bootstrap website. Any help would be appreciated to resolve this.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>IDS PANEL CONFIG</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pos-f-t m-3">
        <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
          <div class="bg p-4">
            <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
            <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar bg">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <h1 style="font-size:50px;">CONFIG</h1>
            <p style="font-size:50px;color: crimson;">Zone report</p>
          <p><strong> please wait...</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class = "container"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap version 5 but your code is for version 4.
If you change `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` and `data-target` to `data-bs-target` it should work.